# Gnuradio: FFT plot for 1 sample

Tags: python, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I'm using GNU Radio for receive radio signal and write it to file (complex) with metadata.
Then I parse file in python and I have variable with 1 sample (8 byte). I want to build FFT plot for just 1 specific sample or save it as image.
Is that real? Can I do that with GRC, or maybe python have lib for that?
Thank you

Comment: The frequency resolution of an FFT is equal to the number of samples that you give it. I don't actually know if the FFT algorithm "works" for a single sample, but if it did, it would give you back just the DC component of the signal. (The "DC component" of a single sample is just the sample value.) If you give it two samples, you get back the DC component and one other frequency component. If you give it 1024 samples, you get back the DC component, and 1023 distinct frequency components, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your question makes no sense: the FFT of a single sample is just *that* sample. That's the definition of an FFT.

Think of it that way: a spectrum tells you which frequencies are in a signal.

What frequency components are in the signal "0.23" ? Only exactly one frequency component: a constant component of amplitude 0.23.

Comment: maybe I put it wrong. I want see freq spectrum for this sample. Like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeaJq.png

Comment: Also note! The spectrum returned by FFT is only "true" if the signal consists exactly of the given sequence of samples, repeated over and over again forever. For a single sample, repeated over and over again forever, the signal obviously is pure DC.

Comment: @jich443, I think you maybe need to explain what you mean by "sample." Normally when talking about digital signal processing, the word "sample" means the value of the signal at one specific instant in time.  Marcus explained why you can not get any information about frequencies from a single _sample_ according to the conventional definition of the word.

Comment: @SolomonSlow if i have metadata for example:
`HEADER 3021
Version Number: 0
Sample Rate: 10000000.00 sps
Seconds: 450.771217
Item size: 8
Data Type: float (5)
Complex? True
Header Length: 171 bytes
Extra Length:  22
Extra Header?  True
Size of Data: 8 bytes
              1.0 items`
and I cut next 8 bytes after this metadata, this is not 1 sample? 1 sample != 1 items?

Comment: @jich443, I don't know the format of the file that you're dealing with, so I don't know if the next 8 bytes following the header is a valid sample, but `Item size: 8` means that each sample takes up 8 bytes in the file. If you extract only 8 bytes, that can not be more than one sample. As explained above, you cannot get frequency information from a single sample.

Comment: @jich443 I addressed exactly what you want in your first comment: you don't get a spectrum from a single sample. That's not how math works.